# extract all localizable strings from a form

Tags: .net, winforms, localization

We have an existing WinForms application which need to be translated.
We want to use a single resource file per solution, so we won't set localizable property of the form.

I would like to develop a tool that, given a form, extract all the localizable hard coded strings in the designer. Something like Visual Studio does when localization property is set to True.
I need to extract only text, captions.

How can I do it?

Second step would be to automatically add extracted strings in the resource file and maybe replace hard coded string with new identifiers.

Comment: Code generated by designer when Localized is true is very different from code generated when the Form won't be localized. Moreover, if you replace hard-coded strings with (for example) methods to read from properties then you'll break Designer. Finally localization **is not just text**. Especially nowadays any excuse to make half perfect work will result in an application with a very poor feedback. The only suggestion I feel to give is to always mark as localizable the forms you want to localize, you can write a tool to read all resx from compiled binaries and to generate satellite assemblies

Comment: (using that kind of tool you can centralize duplicates removal, export to formats suitable for translators and merge from old/new versions). Question: did you consider how they'll translate shortcuts and cues if stripped out from their context? What about RTL layouts? What about images (classical example the "bold" button in Word is different for each language)?

Comment: Not using the built-in support for localization is never not a mistake.  Not just because you need tooling that doesn't exist, the localization service will charge a premium for having to deal with  non-standard ways to do their job.  Quality will be low too since they can't see the context in which the strings are used.

Comment: Maybe i haven't been clear and omitted something.
We need only translation, not full localization.
We'll provide only 2 languages: our locale as default and english.
Probably we'll do the translation internally.
Anyway the question remains the same: how can I extract all localizable strings from a form? how Visual Studio does the work?